# UIlabel shows extra space before text

Tags: ios, device-orientation

I have used UILabel in my app. It is working properly in portrait mode. But when I open my app in landscape mode it shows content in center of UIlabel. I have tried sizeToFit but it is not working. As soon as I increase uilabel's width spacing starts to arrive in uilabel.

My code:

```
self.contentLabel.text = labeltext;
[self.contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[self.contentLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: can you show screenshots for the issues?

Comment: some codes or screenshot please

Comment: http://imgur.com/7fjlwQz,UkjCIf0  This is how my text is displayed in uilabel in landscape mode.

Comment: label text is already aligned to left

Comment: I have checked ny code - sizeToFit works perfectly. Are you sure you run sizeToFit after setting new text and after orientation has been changed?

Comment: when you start your app in landscape mode does it work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your UILabel itself and not the text within it is actually aligning incorrectly upon rotation. Make sure the label stays aligned to the top of the view. Try:

```
self.contentLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

or

```
self.contentLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Edit: One other thought.

If auto layout's enabled and you're calling `sizeToFit` in `viewDidLoad`, perhaps the view is resizing after auto layout lays out the subviews. Try putting your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

Comment: label is aligned to top of the view. but the content is aligned vertically center.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's staying aligned to the top? Especially after using sizeToFit? Have you checked the border position, perhaps using self.contentLabel.layer.borderWidth and self.contentLabel.layer.borderColor?

Comment: I have used background color for label to be sure.

Comment: Oh, OK. Just making sure. ;) Good luck! If I think of any other possible solution, I'll let you know.

Comment: adding my code to viewDidLayoutSubviews works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a UILabel with height bigger than the height of the text, it's normal if that happened and there is no way to change this alignement (Vertical center).

[image]

I have two solutions for this problem:

Work with constraint :

[image]

This constraint Greater than or equal is just magic.

If you create the label with the code I suggest to work with that:

```
UIFont *fontReceive = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
CGSize sizeText = [text sizeWithFont:fontReceive constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(260, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Hope that will help!

Comment: I think i have problem because of font size. because when i used 12 instead of [UIFont systemFontSize] it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to change the height of your cell according the the amount of text your are populating it with.

Please see this code below as an example.

```
NSString *content = **YOUR_STRING_LABEL_INTENDED_CONTENT**
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(390, 1000); //For example - Put in your desired label width here and maximum size etc.

NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] forKey: NSFontAttributeName]; //This allows a calculation to be made of the space taken up, so if you're using a custom or large font it will calculate accordingly.

CGSize newExpectedLabelSize = [content boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;
```

Now you can change the height of your label by using this next line, where label is the name of the label you made.

```
GCRect frame = label.frame;
frame.size.height = newExpectedLabelSize.height;
label.frame = frame;
```

I hope this helps, cheers, Jim.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:'

Comment: the NSString *content = what ever your labelText is

Comment: I have created string variable named labelContent and used 
CGSize newExpectedLabelSize = [labelContent boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;