# UILabel extra spaces before text

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uilabel

I have a label, if i add text to label it added one extra space at the beginning of the text, app supports only portrait orientation. tried following solutions but no use. attached images for reference.

I have created this label in xib with
number of lines 2
with constrains leading, trailing, bottom space to container, height is not fixed,

and set text like

`dealName.text = "￼Cup of Coffee with A asdf asd asdf adsf ads fad"`

[UILabel extra spaces before and after text ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777620/uilabel-extra-spaces-before-and-after-text-ios)

[UIlabel shows extra space before text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847010/uilabel-shows-extra-space-before-text)

**UILabel with multiple lines**

[image: Screen Shot]

**UILabel with single line**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Please check label string may be label string contains spaces.

Comment: double checked, no spaces are there.

Comment: check alignment of label

Comment: Left aligned label. see second line is aligned to left. but not first line.

Comment: Can you please share your code..?

Comment: edited question with details

Comment: The extra space you provided dealName.text = " Cup of Coffee with A asdf asd asdf adsf ads fad" it should be dealName.text = "Cup of Coffee with A asdf asd asdf adsf ads fad".

Comment: Oh God, i didn't see that space in Xcode. Thank you Kathiravan

Answer (score 0):

try this may be there is an any white space before character this will remove this..

```
NSString *trimmed = [yourstring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

yourlable.text = trimmed;
```

OR

Also see if you set attribute **paragraph spacing** from here..

[image]

Comment: i am using just plain text.

Comment: Try trim functions...may be help you